# Maintaining a chat between user and agent using Google Actions

Tags: node.js, chat, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-home

I am creating an app using Dialogflow and Actions on Google Node.js library.
The logic I am trying to implement is as follows:

1. User says: *Initiate chat*.
2. That user request triggers my webhook which then supplies the agent response.
3. User replies back to the agent - this is the tricky part because the user reply can be anything, thus the wrong Intent or the Fallback Intent can be triggered.

Is there a way to allow for the unpredictability of a user's response and to keep conversation going between user and agent? In another words, always trigger the same Intent (Chat Intent) regardless of what the user says?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Dialogflow, you can configure the **Default Fallback Intent** to connect to web fulfillment. In your fulfillment, you can then route the user's query to your webhook and process a response however you'd want.

Comment: Thanks Nick for your response. That's exactly what I did and it works perfectly. Looks to me like this is extremely hacky approach but seems like it is the only way to do it.

Comment: This is the best way to do it in Dialogflow, since it is designed to do the intent matching for you.